# Raspbian Wheezy Audio

Tags: raspbian, audio, hdmi

I've got my new Rpi running with the raspbian wheezy debian distro which is great but I can't seem to play / hear any sound.

Does anyone know if the wheezy distro comes with audio drivers pre-installed or do I need to run some manual commands to install the appropriate drivers?

I'm using the HDMI output to my TV which if I understand correctly, should send audio output as well?

Many Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any extra software but you do need to set the audio out to HDMI. If you are running XBMC then System -> Settings -> System -> Audio output -> Audio output HDMI will do it. You can also specify your speaker configuration and whether your TV or AV amp supports AC3 and/or DTS.

If you aren't running XBMC I'm not sure. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the official Wiki's [Troubleshooting section for Audio](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Sound).

Especially this part:

> Enter the command 'alsamixer' and use the control to check that the
>   volume is up (arrow keys) and that the output is not muted (M key).

The modules should be loaded by default when you're using Wheezy.